# PYTHON DJANGO ORM QUERY for a SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, python-2.7, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

This is regarding Python Django, I have two tables named `"Clients"` and `"Forms"`. Clients table has `primary key` as `id` and a `client name`. Forms table has `primary key` as `id, form name, form details and clientid` - a `foreign key` which references `primary key(id)` in Clients table.

How do I write a `django ORM query` which will display all the forms related to a particular `client id`.
SQL query is `SELECT name, details, id from forms where forms.clientid=Clients.id`

Comment: show what you have tried to write django ORM query?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mean to join any tables, and you want only columns from Form object, so:

```
Forms.objects.filter(clientid=client_id).values("name", "details", "id")
```

Will work for you

Comment: Incase i want to join the tables, is there any method to do so?